# How to release memory using ARC

Tags: ios

I am trying to release memory using ARC.But its not working.

```
xmlData=nil; //NSMutableDataObject
nsurlobject=nil; //NSUrl object
urlrequest=nil; //NSMutableRequest Object
connection=nil; //NSurlConnection Object
```

Its showing same memory when I am checking it on Instruments.

Please tell me where I am going wrong?
Thank you

Comment: How are the objects defined and is anything else retaining them?

Comment: In ARC, setting to nil will only empty the objects. the compiler is responsible for deallocating the allocated objects. so you dont have to worry about that

Comment: If you're creating memory intense objects via convenience methods (`imageNamed:` for example) in a loop, you should surround your loop with `@autoreleasepool` though. Even when using arc.

Comment: Down Voter please mention comment so that i can improve my answer thanks ? –

Comment: make sure that you dont have any retain cycles. Make sure  delegates are weak.

Comment: if these variables are declared as properties, then set them to `nil` with `self.<variable>`

Answer (score 1):

ARC stand for Automatic Reference Counting, When you use ARC in your projects, you dont need to release the memory manually. 
Xcode will detect when the job of the allocated objects is done and release them itself.

You DO NOT have to worry about releasing objects yourself.

Comment: However, if you want to cause objects to be released by ARC sooner, setting them to `nil` can speed ARC up a bit... But it's not really necessary unless you're working with a large amount of memory.

Comment: @DownVoter: Can you please elaborate your down vote ? 
Which will benefit any one else looking out for the same problem and also help me straighten my concepts as well ..

Comment: I'm not responsible for the downvote, but this answer is a bit on the brief side and potentially confusing. Yes, under ARC you no longer have 'manually release' objects yourself, but it's not as simple as " Xcode will detect when the job of the allocated objects is done". You have to make sure you get the 'lifetime qualifiers' correct and set references to nil when appropriate etc. Probably best to reference the [transitioning to arc docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)